Remove the all comments from a SQL view in Azure SQL DW
I need remove the all comments in a SQL view created in Azure SQL Data Warehouse.
Create the query without comments (/* */ ; -- , ...); regular expression functions not working
Query:
CREATE VIEW [dimension].[v_dim_customer] 
AS
    SELECT
        -- primary key
        KNA1.fk_MANDT_KUNNR AS sk_customer, 
        -- attributes
        KNA1.[NAME1_nom], 
        --  KNA1.[DEAR1_concurrents], 
        -- KNA1.[DEAR2_responsable_adv], 
        ----- /*flag client interne/externe*/-----
        flag_ext_int.externe_interne_code, 
        /* flag client interne/externe niveau 2 (détaillé : intra groupe / intra société / externe)*/
        flag_ext_int.externe_interne_level_2_code, 
        --   date pour delta
        -- CY.max_slt_datetime
        -- add --18/12/2023
    FROM 
        [e3p].[KNA1] KNA1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        [e3p].T005T T005T ON KNA1.[fk_MANDT_LAND1] = T005T.[fk_MANDT_LAND1]
                          AND T005T.[bk_SPRAS_code_langue] = N'F' -- français
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         [e3p].T016T ON KNA1.[fk_MANDT_BRSCH] = T016T.[fk_MANDT_BRSCH]
                     
     -- AND KNA1.[SPRAS_code_langue] = T016T.[bk_SPRAS_code_langue]
                     AND T016T.[bk_SPRAS_code_langue] = N'F' -- français
     -- modif ska 03/12 : ajout  delai moyen de paiement, credit autorisé et recommendé
     -- LEFT OUTER JOIN [e3p].[v_KNKK_fr_compute] as KNKK ON KNA1.bk_MANDT_mandant = KNKK.bk_MANDT_mandant
     -- AND KNA1.bk_KUNNR_client = KNKK.bk_KUNNR_client


this might help

Use a T-SQL parser to properly process the nested comments and other oddities, e.g. Michael J Swart: Removing Comments from SQL.

You have several options available to you:

Remove them manually. Definitely not fast or fun, but gets the job done! :D
Copy/paste the script into a text editor (eg. Visual Studio Code, Azure Data Studio), remove the comments using the text editor's regex features, then copy/paste the cleaned script into Azure SQL DW/Azure Synapse.
Similar to option 2, connect to Azure SQL DW/Azure Synapse in Azure Data Studio and directly modify your scripts in there. You'll benefit from improved text editing and management tools, and extensions available in Azure Data Studio.

My preference is option 3 because it lets you modify, test, and deploy the script all in one well-outfitted tool.
You're stuck with option 1 and 2 if you don't have admin access to install the text editors listed above on your local machine.

Thanks for your feedback but I can't edit the SQL script manually.  I have several other SQL queries

CREATE VIEW [dimension].[v_dim_customer] AS 
SELECT
     -- primary key
     KNA1.fk_MANDT_KUNNR AS sk_customer, 
     -- attribut 
     KNA1.[NAME1_nom], 
     flag_ext_int.externe_interne_code, 
     /* flag client interne/externe niveau 2 (détaillé : intra groupe / intra société / externe)*/
     flag_ext_int.externe_interne_level_2_code
     FROM [e3p].[KNA1] KNA1
     LEFT OUTER JOIN [e3p].T005T T005T 
     ON KNA1.[fk_MANDT_LAND1] = T005T.[fk_MANDT_LAND1]
     AND T005T.[bk_SPRAS_code_langue] = N'F' -- français
     LEFT OUTER JOIN [e3p].T016T  
     ON KNA1.[fk_MANDT_BRSCH] = T016T.[fk_MANDT_BRSCH]
     AND T016T.[bk_SPRAS_code_langue] = N'F' -- français

try this, i think that may works

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
